# How to display item images in RDLC Reports

Tags: asp.net, report, rdlc

[But, when i try to create RDCL report from the item tables it shows as "#Error".Image or only first item image is appeared.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8DBI.jpg)

`=Field!ImagePath.Value`

> in ImagePath i have the image directory path of that item image
> [image: Table showing three bicycle items]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to show images of items in my rdlc report.. in rdlc report i have a table in which i show my items detail eg. id, name,price etc know i want to to show the image of the item in that table is use about expression in rdlc image tool inside the cell of table. which show only the image of first item in the table. hope you understant

Answer (score 0):

open image properties and change update the MIME Type

[image]